# Duplicate headllines in org mode in CentOS

Tags: org-mode, magit, linux

CentOS 7

Emacs 27.1

Magit

Here my folder with org mode files:
[image]

I open **current.to.do.org** and it success open.

[image]

As you can see the first headline is **ANDROID** and last headline is **TESTING**.

Nice.

Now I restart Emacs and open again **current.to.do.org**.
But now all headlines ARE DUPLICATE.

[image]

I exit from Emacs and start like this:

```
emacs -Q
```

But result is a same.

[image]

Another test:

Create new org file (**test.current.org**). It has only one headline (**First headline**)
[image]

Save file. Size of file is **49 Bytes**

[image]

Exit from Emacs. And go to folder again.
[image]

As you can see the size of file (test.current.org) not change.
Nice. And now open file again.

[image]

As you can see the whole data ARE DUPLICATE!
It's happen every time!!!

Comment: Has that happened more than once? If not, I would strongly suspect that it was something you did without realizing it. If it happens regularly, then I suggest you become very conscious of your actions before saving the file. I doubt very much that this is caused by emacs or a package.

Comment: @NickD  it happens regularly

Comment: Bisect your init file: you must have added something that does this.

Comment: @NickD I use package "magit". If I remove this package the problem is gone.

Comment: Since you opened [a different question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64677/magit-not-correct-work-with-emacs-27-2-duplicate-text) on the `magit` problem, you should close this one.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because the OP has opened a [more specific question](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64677/magit-not-correct-work-with-emacs-27-2-duplicate-text) on this problem.

Comment: @NickD I found the problem.

In my init.el I has :

'(auto-revert-tail-mode t t)

If remove this setting then problem (duplication) is gone.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Magit not correct work with Emacs 27.2 - duplicate text](https://emacs.stackexchange.com/questions/64677/magit-not-correct-work-with-emacs-27-2-duplicate-text)

Comment: @JensKubieziel  I think this problem appears when use magit AND '(auto-revert-tail-mode t t).
If use only (auto-revert-tail-mode t t) - the problem is gone.
If use only package magit the problem is gone.